# ¿Cómo optimizar el diseño web responsive y darle estilo a los iconos png css?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Diseño web adaptable responsive al tener varias resoluciones el código seria demasiado extenso. Cómo optimizar el código de los estilos css existe una forma mejor para compactar para evitar los estilos css demasiado extenso.

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){
#header {
 width: 800px;
}
#area {
 width:800px;
}

#footer{
 width: 800px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
#header {
 width: 600px;
}
#area {
 width:600px;
}

#footer{
 width: 600px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
#header {
 width: 400px;
}
#area {
 width:400px;
}

#footer{
 width: 400px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
#header {
 width: 320px;
}
#area {
 width:320px;
}

#footer{
 width: 320px;
}
}
```

Menciono extenso por tener que adaptar la plantilla y aparte aptar el contenido.

Por otra parte como puedo darle estilo a los iconos png

No me gusta utilizar librerías extensas para utilizar iconos me gusta más los códigos optimizados pero al llamar iconos de una imagen png

```
.icon-mail:before{
  content: url(../font/icons/icon-mail.png);
}
```

No puedo cambiarle el ancho ni el alto de la imagen ni cambiarle el color, existe alguna forma para darle estilos a los iconos png.

Comment: para cambiar el color de los png, puedes usar `filter` pero no es una solucion 100% cross browser. http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es demasiado extensa para el formato de SOes, pero hay una solución a eso que te parece abrumador: existen lenguajes para pre-procesar CSS, entre ellos, LESS, SASS, Compass, etc. Con estos preprocesadores puedes usar funciones, constantes, fórmulas, agrupar tus estilos en diferentes archivos, usar mixins para evitar repetir código... Mira uno de estos lenguajes: http://sass-lang.com/guide y te recomiendo que visites el sitio de Bootstrap para que veas como aprovechar los preprocesadores de CSS.

Comment: Me cuesta entender qué es lo que se pide en la pregunta. ¿Quieres optimizar el código en general?¿quieres saber cómo cambiar el tamaño/color de un div?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hola amigo son dos preguntas en una para evitar crear tantas preguntas, si puedes observar el estilo `icon-mail:before` es igual que se utiliza en las librerías de iconos solo que yo lo estoy realizando manualmente mediante imágenes png la cual aquellas imágenes las muestro de esta manera  `<i class="icon-phone"></i>` no veo cual es la confusión de la pregunta pero si puedes explicarme mejor para editarla aunque yo veo claro mi pregunta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro exacto amigo quiero optimizar el código general del diseño u estilo css responsive es decir alguna otra forma de compactar para no repetir la misma función `@media screen and (max-width:800px)`  al crear varias resoluciones (800px, 600px, 400px, 320)  para ende así no tener un código demasiado extenso.

Comment: @toledano Gracias amigo tomare en cuenta la recomendaciones, aunque sinceramente no me gusta tener que insertar librerías extensas como las de Bootstrap cuando en realidad no se utiliza todo el código me gusta más crear mis propios estilos ende así son más cortos y optimizados me libro de tener código que no se utiliza del todo como los estilos css de Bootstrap.

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien. La mención de Bootstrap no es porque recomiende usarla, sino como ejemplo de como se usan los preprocesadores. La grid de Bootstrap usa de forma intensiva funciones y mixins, y aunque no te guste Boostrap puedes aprender. La pregunta debería replantearse para hacerse más concreta, dos preguntas en un solo post no es lo esperado.

Comment: @toledano ok amigo gracias, si lo siento son dos preguntas pero son cortas que se enlaza a una misma función que son los estilos css, pero gracias por responder saludos.

Comment: @J.Doe Aún no entiendo a qué te refieres con [este comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18547/c%c3%b3mo-optimizar-el-dise%c3%b1o-web-responsive-y-darle-estilo-a-los-iconos-png-css?noredirect=1#comment30188_18547) ¿tienes las mismas propiedades repetidas para todas las resoluciones?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Claro amigo tengo las misma propiedades repetidas porque son diferentes resoluciones  porque no puedo utilizar una sola propiedad para crear varias resoluciones obligadamente debo utilizar varias propiedades o no es así porque la idea es optimizar y si existe una mejor forma mucho mejor.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo de dicha repetición a la pregunta? Porque me parece que o bien estás intentando reinventar la rueda, o bien no estás diseñando bien los estilos

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro amigo acabo de editar mi pregunta espero sea clara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre la optimización de las `@media` *queries*, debes recordar que los estilos definidos en la raíz del documento se usarán de manera general y los estilos de las `@media` queries serán condicionales a que se cumpla la restricción indicada, "heredando" los estilos más generales.

En la pregunta pones esto:

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    //estilos
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    //estilos
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    //estilos
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    //estilos
}
```

Pero realmente ese esquema sería algo así:

```
// estilos generales que se aplicarán para todos los tamaños de pantalla

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    // sólo modificaciones a los estilos de arriba (general)
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    // sólo modificaciones a los estilos de arriba (general + 800)
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    // sólo modificaciones a los estilos de arriba (general + 800 + 600)
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    // sólo modificaciones a los estilos de arriba (general + 800 + 600 + 400)
}
```

De este modo no estarías repitiendo reglas CSS (en algunos casos será imposible de evitar), sólo se definirían las generales y luego se contaría con que caerían en cascada sobre todas las resoluciones, y de manera similar las diferentes condicionales.

Por ejemplo, si tienes:

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    #header {
        width: 800px;
        font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:2em;
        color:red;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #header {
        width: 600px;
        font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:1.5em;
        color:red;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    #header {
        width: 400px;
        font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:1.2em;
        color:red;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #header {
        width: 320px;
        font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:1em;
        color:red;
    }
}
```

Eso podría simplificarse así:

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    #header {
        width: 800px;
        font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:2em;
        color:red;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #header {
        width: 600px;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    #header {
        width: 400px;
        font-size:1.2em;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #header {
        width: 320px;
        font-size:1em;
    }
}
```

---

Sobre cómo En lugar de agregar la imagen en el `content`, podrías dejar el `content` vacío y añadir le imagen como fondo del `:before` y eso sí te daría más control sobre su tamaño (usando `background-size:cover`). Así podrías definir diferentes tamaños de imagen dependiendo de los diferentes tamaños de pantalla.

Por ejemplo:

```css
div::before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: perfecto amigo muchas gracias. Disculpa por las molestias al no haber sido clara mi pregunta.